# Simple Alternate Art Style

Tags: art

I'm looking for suggestions on easy or simple art styles that can be created by anyone. It would be for a 2D game, but pixel art isn't really my thing. An example from a game would help. Thank you very  much.

Comment: You mean "How to create art without any artistic talent"?

Comment: I think this is a polling question. It won't produce a single answer that's correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to create a game without access to artistic talent to create artwork, you could go for a graphic style which is rather abstract than representative. You could, for example, represent all gameplay objects with geometric shapes, like in Geometry Wars.

Answer (score 4):

Some games, such as [roguelikes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike), feature graphics made up of nothing but colored ASCII characters.  Dwarf fortress is a deep and complex game modeled after roguelikes.  Here's what its graphics look like:

[image: dwarf fortress]

Answer (score 1):

Making it look childish isn't a bad idea at hindsight. Look at [An Untitled Story](http://www.mattmakesgames.com/).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Vector art. Check Revange of the Titans.

Comment: -1. Vector art isn't simple nor easy. Creating compelling/pleasing vector-art isn't something everyone is capable of.